# Por que o arredondamento se comporta diferente de linguagem para linguagem?

Tags: matemática, característica-linguagem, arredondamento, convenções

Andei analisando a saída dos métodos nativos de arredondamento das linguagens abaixo. Eu testei o número **0,5** em todos abaixo:

| Linguagem | Obs. | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Java](https://ideone.com/a8mQZs) |  | 1 |
| [JavaScript](https://ideone.com/e36Vgv) |  | 1 |
| [Python 2](https://ideone.com/Qx7dtE) |  | 1 |
| [Python 3](https://ideone.com/A4sVCS) |  | 0 |
| [PHP](https://ideone.com/cb66NK) |  | 1 |
| [Go](https://ideone.com/c0c1io) |  | 1 |
| [C](https://ideone.com/CZYotn) | GCC 8.3 | 1 |
| [C++](https://ideone.com/6TIcR4) | GCC 8.3 e `<tgmath.h>` | 1 |
| [SQLite](https://ideone.com/K4OMri) |  | 1 |
| [R](https://ideone.com/BAFt4r) |  | 0 |
| [C#](https://ideone.com/HiXJUg) |  | 0 |
| [VB.NET](https://ideone.com/CjzrSC) |  | 0 |

Por que algumas linguagens apresentam `1` como resultado e outras `0` para a mesma entrada?

Comment: Eu acho que as que resultaram em 1 optaram por arredondar para cima, enquanto as que resultaram em 0 optaram por arredondar para baixo xD

Comment: Notem que PHP tem modos para ajustar o caso: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#refsect1-function.round-parameters - PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP Arredonda num para longe de zero quando está na metade, transformando 1,5 em 2 e -1,5 em -2.
PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN Arredonda num para zero quando está na metade, transformando 1,5 em 1 e -1,5 em -1.
PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN Arredonda num para o valor par mais próximo quando está na metade do caminho, transformando 1,5 e 2,5 em 2.
PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD Arredonda num para o valor ímpar mais próximo quando está na metade, transformando 1,5 em 1 e 2,5 em 3.

Comment: PHP por padrão usa `$mode=PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP`

Comment: C# tambem tem ajuste especifico: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-7.0 --- JavaScript esta documentado: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-math.round, Python https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round (extra: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É muito difícil responder isso sem recorrer ao velho e tradicional "os criadores decidiram assim".

Talvez seja possível encontrar um rationale publicado em cada tecnologia que explica por que fizeram esta escolha ([C# tem explicação do geral do Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding/) e [no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/311696/221800), não vou pegar todas). Pode ser que nem pensaram sobre, e que apenas fizeram o que estavam acostumados.

Lembrando que não é bem a linguagem que faz isso e sim a biblioteca, provavelmente padrão. Então pode usar uma outra biblioteca que se comporte diferente na mesma linguagem.

Pode acontecer até de ter um comportamento diferente no que seria o mesmo método. Se usar uma função de arredondamento em C# em uma expressão LINQ que será transformada em um código SQL terá o comportamento do C# ou do SQL daquele banco de dados?

Os dois resultados são possíveis, na verdade até mais, porque pode ser que dê algo diferente em um valor negativo, ou se for ímpar ou par.

Existem diversas maneiras de definir o que é o meio do caminho (*midpoint*), ou seja, se o 0.5 está mais para o próximo número ou o anterior, e definir qual é o próximo, se é o maior ou se é o que vai na sequência do incremento.

Qualquer biblioteca decente terá como dizer qual é o critério que deseja usar. Quase sempre é escolhido um padrão que se você não informar é o critério adotado, mas deve ter opção, caso contrário a biblioteca é ruim. [Em C# tem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), [Java também](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html), mas não para `float` e não permite arredondar com casas decimais de forma inexata (C# tem [no `decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round?view=net-8.0) também). E PHP de forma limitada. [Go tem uma opção extra](https://pkg.go.dev/math#RoundToEven). Foi "interessante" fazer essa pesquisa em algumas linguagens, me impressionou a limitação.

Algumas "linguagens" têm um padrão diferente dependendo da função usada. E isso já indica o que quer usar. Em alguns casos precisa dizer passando um argumento dizendo como quer que arredonde. Eu imagino que está pegando sempre o que arredonda fazendo uma seleção de acordo com o valor. Tem função que vai sempre para o anterior ou seguinte e não para o que tem mais proximidade. Não vou aqui falar de `Ceiling()`, `Floor()` e `Truncate()` que a pergunta não fala, e tem mais clareza como arredonda, e não muda com um valor bem no meio do caminho, que parece ser o foco da pergunta.

Algumas da lista dando 0 (não verifiquei se está tudo certo) escolheram na função de proximidade (geralmente o `Round()`) o que eu considero um erro para padrão, mas não tem problema se está documentado e tem como usar de outra forma. De fato, em cada situação você tem que pensar o que você espera para escolher o que deseja, e em alguns casos a escolha será não precisar dizer nada, porque o método já fez a escolha para você quando não informa. Em outros não.

O ideal seria que a maioria dos casos não precisasse dizer o que deseja. Há quem discorde disso. mas sempre tem que pensar sobre.

Eu penso que seguindo a matemática em vez de pular de 1 em 1, pula de 0.5 em 0.5, o 0.5 seria o equivalente ao 0 da faixa, então 0.5 já faz parte de outra faixa. Ou seja, se tem uma faixa de inteiros de 10 números começa em 0 e termina 9, o 10 já é outra dezena, e se vai até meio, então começa em 0 e vai até quase 0.5, o 0.5 já é outra faixa.

O problema fica com os valores negativos, nem eu sei bem o que é melhor. Se usar exatamente o mesmo critério, O -0.5 arredondaria para -1.0, certo? Sim se você considerar o 0 como parte dos números negativos. Mas aí o 0 seria usado duas vezes, o mais correto seria começar no menor negativo efetivamente negativo (não neutro). Aí o 0.5 faria parte da faixa inicial, então -0.5 deveria arredondar para 0. É mais sensato matematicamente e é estranho, e pode não dar o resultado esperado se tiver troca de sinais pura e simples. Por isso que trabalhar com sinais é bem complicado em tudo. A matemática nunca teve uma boa solução.

**O teste sempre precisa ser feito com negativo também**.

Eu gosto menos ainda quando muda quando o número próximo é par ou ímpar. Mas tem seu mérito para evitar acumulação de arredondamentos. Isso pra mim é o mesmo que usar implementação inexata de número.

**O teste deve ser feito sempre com algo próximo do par e do ímpar**. Veja tabela abaixo.

Aí tem que entender todas as implicações e usar da melhor forma em cada caso. Se você for no padrão sem pensar poderá ter resultados errados. O programador relapso usará sem pensar no resultado, vai encontrar o resultado que deseja e se dar por satisfeito, em vez de dedicar um tempo para provar que em qualquer situação dará o resultado esperado, mesmo que para isso precise usar alguma técnica adicional para ajudar ao que precisa.

Tem caso que pouco importa, assim como tem caso que um `float` dá resultado preciso, porém inexato, mas ainda é útil.

Eu estou pegando a metade de inteiros, mas vale para outras magnitudes, vale o mesmo para 0.05 ou 0.005 por exemplo.

[Retirado da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding):

[image: tabela onde vai o arredondamento]

Não são poucas combinações:

[image: tabela de combinações possíveis]

Embora tenha razão para usar, não gosto do aleatório para maioria dos casos, e geralmente nem pode usar.

Pelo que entendi da pergunta, interessa mais a coluna "Round to nearest".

[*Link* com um teste mais amplo](https://semuserable.com/posts/flavours_of_rounding/).

Alguns exemplos feitos com todos os casos para entender melhor:

#### [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BpHUMv). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jdtW5Y). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/Rounding.cs).

#### [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#round)

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oKT0BU). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/bsrqxbghis-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/RoundingMidPoint.py).

#### [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round)

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jMgxW1). E [no **repl.it**](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/RoundingMidPoint.sql). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://replit.com/join/ilwixblkpq-maniero).

#### [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#round(float))

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/en3DcN). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/tviqzjfxgr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/Rounding.java).

#### [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9USe9f). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Math/Rounding.js).

#### [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Vud9zI). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/meaeombaxv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/Rounding.php).

#### [Go](https://pkg.go.dev/math#Round)

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Vud9zI). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/fjaojmzpyg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Go/Rounding.go).

#### [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round)

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8eNSvM). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/oxxajeuyyh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Rounding.c).

Lembrando que usei o *default* quando tinha a opção. E posso ter falhado em achar uma outra forma em alguma caso.

Ao que tudo indica parece que algumas linguagens escolheram o tal do *bankers rounding* e aí é que está a diferença.

Nem entrei na questão de que pode (exemplos hipotéticos) 1.5 e 2.5 arredondar para 2.0 pela [falta de exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101) (mesmo sem considerar ímpar ou par), é que na memória não é bem o número que está vendo e um deles pode pender mais para um lado porque ele não está no meio exato, já que ele não existe em tipos inexatos. Vai depender do tipo do dado e como a "linguagem" lida com isso.

Também não entrei em questões específicas colaterais que o arredondamento pode precisar acumular a diferença e aplicar em outro número, caso típico de prestações.

Conclusão: leia a documentação antes de usar. O de sempre. Faça uma escolha, mesmo que seja o *default*. Não deixe o *default* escolher por você. Não ache que é fácil. Ele é perigoso até por parecer que é problema simples de resolver e entender. Não se engane, não é, tem que pensar em todas as consequências mesmo, não negligencie isso.

Answer (score 3):

O resultado diferente do arredondamento de linguagem para outra linguagem vai da regra de arredondamento adotada.

Alguns mecanismos de arredondamento usado pode ser diferente de cada uma, eis alguns metodos de arredondamento:

- Round-to-even (bankers' rounding)
- Round-up (arredondamento para cima)
- Round-down (arredondamento para baixo)
- Round-toward-zero (arredondamento em direção a zero)
- Round-toward-positive-infinity (arredondamento em direção ao infinito
  positivo)

Só para ter um comparativo usarei `python` e `C++` para mostrar a diferença

No python  foi usado o *round-to-even*, na documentação oficial menciona **"** *round-half-to-even* **"** e sua importância para a linguagem, antes tinha um detalhe na versão **2**.**7** ocorreu um **[bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue21179)** devido não ter seguido o padrão  **[IEEE 754](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8766229)**  **(** *é um padrão internacional para representação e aritmética de números de ponto flutuante* **)** e o arredondamento de "**0.5**" não era preciso referente ao metodo adotado pela linguagem mas nas versões posteriores corrigiu e implementou o padrão

O **round-to-even**  arredonda para o inteiro mais próximo mas se houver dois inteiros equidistantes, o número é arredondado para o inteiro **par** mais próximo.

eis um exemplo dessa metodologia em python :

```
>>> round(0.5)
0
>>> round(2.5)
2
```

Em comparação a linguagem `C++`, é utilizado a ideia do **round-to-nearest** que arredonda o número quando está no meio exato entre dois valores inteiros si baseando na norma **ISO/IEC 14882:2017**.
Não tenho 100% de certeza mas C++ tambem inclui "round half away from zero" e diferente do python C++ tem como critério o desempate para o valor **ímpar** mais próximo em caso de equidistância

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    double numeroA = 0.5; 
    double numeroB = 1.5;
 
    int rnumeroA = round(numeroA);
    int rnumeroB = round(numeroB);
 
    
    cout <<  numeroA << " arredondado : " << rnumeroA << endl;
    cout <<  numeroB << " arredondado : " << rnumeroB << endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

saída:

```
0.5 arredondado : 1
1.5 arredondado : 2
```

Usando como ponto inicial essas duas linguagens da para ter uma noção do motivo de não terem o mesmo resultado.
Em c++ é mais pela precisão enquanto python é para diminuir o erro quando ha empate entre arredondar para cima ou para baixo.